# Worksheet_change event to add character in front of every populated cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to add a `'` character before each cell that has a value on a worksheet when a `worksheet_change()` event triggers? For instance, if a cell is modified, I would like the code to run through every cell on the worksheet and add a `'` in front of each populated cells value.

`3/31/2021` converted to `'3/31/2021`

`$56.092` converted to `'$56.092`

`59.5%` converted to `'59.5%`

### Edit

Below is an example used to achieve this method; however, this performs slow over large datasets that may be pasted in.

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Target

    If cell <> "" Then
        cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
    End If
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely possible. Are you debugging specific code you've already attempted?

Comment: @BigBen tried using a for loop in conjunction with a range classification, but it's very slow on a 30000 x 100 worksheet (has blank cells too).

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your question with the code you've tried. Also, likely goin to be faster if you use an [array](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Just to get this straight, every time any cell changes you want VBA to analyze 3,000,000 cells to see if any of them need a `'` added? How could that be anything but slow? Or maybe I'm reading this wrong and you only want the cell that was changed to be checked and modified? Can you clarify?

Comment: 2 options: 1) Assuming that all the data is already how you want it... and you only want to do constant "housekeeping" simply use the `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
    `Target = "'" & Target`
`End Sub` (most basic version, will require addntl lines)
2) depending on why you need the commas there, you might be fine to set your whole sheet's data type to "text". That will stop excel from trying to change your data to dates, or times...

Comment: BigBen, JNevill, @cameron-critchlow; Sorry for the lack of context, the end goal is to have the sheet preserve the custom formatting in a text value. The edit achieves this, but is terribly slow even on a small dataset.

Comment: Oh, well that's a much more involved problem. When you add a "'" before data, it won't preserve your custom formatting. it will just stick the apostrophe before the raw data entered. are all the cells you want this done to supposed to be in the same 3 formats as above? And you you manually typing the "$"? and What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @CameronCritchlow, it could honestly be in any type of custom formatting that the user designates. Just looking to store that formatting in a text value somehow. The purpose behind this is that we are using an excel reader and the reader only sees the underlying data type and not the custom format.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only apply formatting to the last cell edited... but as long as the existing data is good this housekeeping should be enough. you can loop the same code to correct your existing data if need be.
I haven't tested it on every data type, but it works on the handful I did test.

On Sheet Module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target <> "" Then
            Target.Value = "'" & Format(Target, Target.NumberFormat)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tested this out; do you know if there is a way to handle the `_)` or `_` from not appearing in the cell when the custom formatting includes this? Only solution I can think of is to check format type then pop the `_)` or `_` out, but wondering if there is something more efficient.

Comment: Well, you could run the output through a replace formula:: `Target.Value = "'" & Replace(Format(Target, Target.NumberFormat), "_", "")`, nest two replace functions to remove both.